# Will Google index all the forum topics if they share one PHP file and use URL parameters?

Tags: seo, web-development, url-parameters, forum, clean-urls

So there is a website which is has dozens of themes e.g.->

- cats
- Ford
- birds
- NASA...  U get the point.

And then every theme has a unique topic.

- cats  ->> Topic1, Topic2,.....
- Ford->> Topic1, Topic2,.....
- birds ->> Topic1, Topic2,.....
- NASA...->> Topic1, Topic2,.....

And last, every topic has discussion part. Just like a typical forum I guess.

How would it work with search engines?   How would Google show the correct theme name for relevant searches?
Do we need to create a .php file for every theme (which means dozens of files) or will Google index the parameters and show them to the person who searched?

If we do need separate PHP files, it would be so many files.  That seems opposite to PHP spirit of code reuse.  If we call the page `theme.php/id=?`  could google index it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Will Google index all the forum topics if they share one PHP file and use URL parameters?***

Short answer? Yes.

More than one site I had was all parameter driven just like you are suggesting. One with millions of pages. They all worked fine in the search engines.

You will want to concentrate on on-page SEO and not rely specifically on the parameters. For example, put into the title and h1, h2, ... tags important signals for search.

Comment: It might also help to have a specific `<link rel="canonical" href=…`, with the href containing the relevant parameters.  That will make it more obvious that the parameters are essential to the page, and not for cosmetic formatting etc.